# scope of local variables of a function in C

Tags: c++, c, scope

I have heard about the following scenario right when I started programming in C.

"**Trying to access from outside, a functions local variable will result in error (or garbage value). Since the stack gets cleared off when we return from the function**"

But my below code sample prints a value of 50. I am compiling the code with latest GCC compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * left();

int main()
{
      int *p=left();
      printf("%d\n",*p);
      return 0;
}

int * left()
{
        int i=50;
        return &i;
}
```

Enlight me on this issue.

**Can I know the behaviour in C++ ?? Is it similar to c ..**

Comment: Think of it like stealing - you're not supposed to do it, and it's not guaranteed to work. But sometimes you might get away with it. That doesn't make it the right thing to do.

Comment: So isn't there any strict standard saying what we can do and what we cant do. Until now I believed it cant be done and should not be done. But now since it is not a rule a newbie can think we can do it ?/

Comment: The standard does say what you should and should not do.  It just rarely defines what will go wrong if you do not follow said instructions.

Comment: I think it would be best to define it as illegal than undefined ... since undefine says anything can happen.

Comment: I never said there wasn't a rule; s other answers indicate it results in undefined behavior. I was just suggesting an analogy for why it might seem to work even though it's not something you should do.

Comment: Undefined behavior literally means that anything can happen. Any other approach would require something _defined_ to happen, and that places a burden on the compiler and runtime library to insert the necessary checks (e.g. in your case, it would have to somehow validate every pointer before use), which can potentially impose a significant performance penalty. Core philosophy of both C and C++ is to avoid such penalties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify it to add a second call to `printf` and you'll see a different value from the first time. Compile it with optimizations turned on and you'll see another set of values. Do *anything* with the value and you're stepping into undefined territory, which means that the compiler is free to summon demons through your nasal passages.

On my system, I see `50` and then `0`; with optimizations I see `0` and then `32767`.

If you make the local variable `static`, then you can return its address since it becomes just like a global (but remember that there is only one instance of it).

When a function returns, the local storage it was using on the stack is now considered "unused" by the program, since the stack doesn't go that high anymore. Typically, though, the values are still there, since there's no urgent need to clear them. The memory is also still owned by the program, since there's no sense in returning memory to the operating system a few bytes at a time. So for your specific example, under the circumstances in which you compiled it, the memory pointed to still contains the value `50`. Officially, though, the value of `*p` is *indeterminate*, and attempts to use it result in *undefined* behavior.

One existential crisis of the C language is how on the one hand, it says nothing about the stack and the various bits of hexadecimal sludge that make up a running process; on the other hand, it's necessary to understand those in order to protect yourself from crashes, buffer overflows, and undefined behavior. Just remember that you're lucky that GCC gives a warning for this.

Comment: offcourse adding optimizations might change the output value as the compiler trys to optimize the code

Comment: "on the other hand, it's necessary to understand those". It certainly helps to understand them, since then it's easier to remember what you can and can't do. But it's not strictly necessary provided you obey the standard. In this case, don't reference an object whose lifetime has expired (the lifetime of automatic variables ends when their block is exited). You don't need to know that this is implemented using a stack. The one thing you generally do need to avoid, in a platform-specific way, is running out of stack, i.e. don't recurse too deep.

Answer (score 12):

The variable 'i' is created on the stack and when the function 'left' returns, the stack is cleared. When I say cleared, it means the address used by variable 'i' is marked free for reuse. Till some other portion of code uses the same address, the value will remain unmodified. In your case, it is plain luck that gives you desired results. If you call few more functions after call to 'left', I am fairly certain you will get wrong results.

Comment: Thats true .. i am getting different behaviour when I call the function in between

Comment: @codingfreak: also try it with the `-O2` optimization.  On my test with GCC 3.4.5 I had `2009147472` output - GCC likely simply optimized away the store of `50` into the variable since the variable was never otherwise used during its lifetime.

Comment: Can I know the behaviour in C++ ??

Comment: C++ works exactly the same as C in this case.  *p value would be undefined.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior according to the C standard is undefined not garbage values.  So it's possible, and occasionally likely, that the value will remain unchanged.  This is not guaranteed by any means.

This is working by luck / chance / accident and nothing else.  Don't rely on this behavior because it **will** come back to bite you.

Comment: Can I know the behaviour in C++ ??

Comment: The behaviour for the code you posted in C++ is the same: undefined behaviour.

Comment: You mean even in C++ we should avoid using the way shown above ?? But I have came across same kind of program in C++ primer plus in chapter 8 where the author is dynamically allocating memory in the user-defined function and freeing it on returning it to main function.

Comment: @codingfreak The C++ example you saw was very different from returning the adress of a local variable. The local variable's storage is automatically freed when the function returns. You saw an example where the storage wasn't freed automatically -- and thus needed to be freed explicitly by the programmer.

Comment: @Pascal - I agree with you. But dont you think it can send wrong message to new programmers that we can also do in the way given in example ??

Answer (score 3):

Look at this modified example, where it shows clearly if something goes in between:

```
int *p=left();
// right here
printf("%d\n",*p);
```

You get a corrupted stack easily. The idea is that you don't own that place, someone else could use it!

```
int main()
{
    int *p=left();
    right(); // Look here!  
    printf("%d\n",*p); // prints -50 instead of 50
    return 0;
}
...
int * right()
{
    int i=-50;
    return &i;
}
```

Comment: The variable named "i" in right() is not the same one as in left(); it just happens to have the same name and use the same memory.  Note however that p is not assigned to the address of right()'s i; it still has the address of left()'s i.

Comment: @Nathan I am just trying to show how a stack can get corrupted easily if something goes in between, whether we use `right` or any code that uses the stack in the same thread :)

Answer (score 2):

It works by **accident**.
Memory location pointed by `p` still contains integer value 50 when `printf()` is called.
But call to any function inside `main()` between `left()` and `printf()` would overwrite it.

For example, I don't know what would happen in your implementation if you changed your `printf()` call to:

```
printf("abs(%d) = %d ???\n", *p, abs(*p));
```

Don't do it!

Comment: Yeah calling another function between is changing the value

Comment: See my response for the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to an object beyond its lifetime (the scope of `left()`). That results in undefined behaviour - I'd guess that you still get 50 because nothing has overwritten the area where `i` was yet.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the C standard is concerned, the value is undefined.

Practically, as long as nothing is pushed to the stack before the returned value is referenced, it works, but the next time a function is called the return address and new stack frame are pushed to the stack and may overwrite the referenced value.

This would not be considered acceptable coding (because of the undefined nature).

Comment: It's not just the _value_ that's undefined, it's the _behavior_ that's undefined. You can get an access violation there. You can overwrite some system structure and crash the whole OS (think DOS and the likes). In fact, you can make your monitor blow up in your face. ~

Comment: "If you have a sound card it swears at you" - http://www.dilbert.com/strips/comic/1995-09-17/

Comment: I agree that it's both the value and the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior. `i` is destroyed upon leaving `left()`. You have an address to garbage in `p`. The compiler hasn't destroyed `i` by luck, yet.